# C# Web API 2 and Angular: Display report on Angular error

Tags: c#, reporting-services, asp.net-web-api2, ssrs-2012

I have a C# Web API 2 and Angular 2 app. I am trying to display a report in my frontend and I have the following code:

backend code:

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetReport() {
  byte[] bytes;
  using (var reportViewer = new ReportViewer()) {
    Stream s = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(@"C:\Projects\MyReportProject\report_sample.rdl");
    reportViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
    reportViewer.LocalReport.LoadReportDefinition(s);

    bytes = reportViewer.LocalReport.Render("Pdf");
    var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    Stream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
    result.Content = new StreamContent(s);
    result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
    return result;
  }
}
```

frontend code:

```
<iframe height="200" width="600" src="/api/Report/GetReport"></iframe>
```

`Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: report
System.ArgumentNullException
at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Report.LoadReportDefinition(Stream report)`

**Note: My API and my report are on separate projects.**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This has nothing to do with angular. `Stream s = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(@"C:\Projects\MyReportProject\report_sample.rdl")` is evaluating to `null`

Comment: You mean I shouldn't tag Angular? I'm not really sure of what I'm doing so I apologize.

Comment: that's exactly what I mean. I already removed the tag though.

Comment: Okay thanks very much.